# SQL INSERT INTO combining data from another table with a constant

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build a table, bringing together data from multiple other tables. I need four pieces of information brought into this new table (Date, Amount, Person, Description). For some of my source tables, that's easy, I can just use:

```
$example = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO bigtable (Date, Amount, Person, Description)
   SELECT PayDate, Amount, Payee, Description
   FROM Payments
   WHERE Payee=Bob  
");
```

But for some of them, the Description field doesn't exist, but could be created by just using the same value for all items added via this particular query. So the question is this: I know how to insert a single record using values, but how can I insert a bunch of records programatically such that some fields are pulled dynamically from the other table (as above) and others are a value I specify (e.g, Income from Stream A). My incomplete effort is below.

```
$combiner3 = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO ".$name."accttemptable (Date, Amount)
SELECT PayDate, Cash 
FROM IncomeStreamA  
");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand you right you can use `UNION ALL`.

```
INSERT INTO bigtable (`Date`, Amount, Person, Description)
SELECT PayDate, Amount, Payee, Description
  FROM Payments
 WHERE Payee='Bob' 
 UNION ALL
SELECT PayDate, Cash, 'Bob', 'Your description'
  FROM IncomeStreamA
 UNION ALL
SELECT SomeDate, SomeAmount, Firstname, 'Description'
  FROM Table3
...
```

Second select is just an example and assumes that everything that comes from `IncomeStreamA` pertains to Bob. Change it appropriately.

You can build your nonexistent values on fly with `CASE WHEN`. For example

```
SELECT SomDate,
       SomeAmount,
       CASE somecolumn 
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Bob' 
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Jhon' 
           ELSE 'Other'
       END Person, 
       'Your description' Description
 FROM SomeTable
```

You can chain as many select as you need to achieve your goal.